# How does a machine determine its host name?

Tags: dns, hosts-file, hostname, solaris-10

Below is the output of the `hostname` command.

```
bash-3.2$ hostname
server1
```

How does the `hostname` command determine the hostname to be `server1`? I guess it checks with the DNS server as this is something the DNS should do.. or does it get this information from `/etc/hosts/` file or some other local file?

```
bash-3.2$ cat /etc/hosts
#
# Internet host table
#
127.0.0.1       localhost
123.123.9.133   server1       loghost
123.123.9.134      load-balancer.tsg.ge.com load-balancer
bash-3.2$ uname
SunOS
```

Comment: @mpy - My bad.. I didn't want to use the actual IPs and server names I work with. I missed to mask the server name. I corrected it above. Would you be so kind to delete the above comment for the same reason. Looking forward to your inputs. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I deleted my comment. But be aware that your actual server name is still in the (public accessible) revision history of your question!

Answer (score 2):

First, the way to resolve names is configured usually in /etc/nsswitch.conf. You will have a line like :

> hosts:      files dns

That means it will first read the **file** /etc/hosts and if not resolve ask the DNS.

Now, as stated in `man hostname` the name of a machine is configured in the system and queried with the system call `gethostname()`. This is the same with `uname`which gives **kernel name** without argument and nodename with `uname -n` which probably gets its information from `gethostname()`too.

So the answer to this command has nothing to do either with DNS nor /etc/hosts other than that's probably how it is set at boot-time by the kernel, but that depends from the distribution/UNIX flavor you're using.

Comment: Thanks Kwaio. I am looking into `gethostname()` now. This is quite informative and is exactly the direction I was hoping this discussion to take.